# How to find the probability that a randomly chosen packet contains exactly one defective diskette

Tags: probability

A computer accessories distributor obtains its supply of diskettes from manufacturers A and B with 60% of the diskettes from manufacturer A. The diskettes are packed by the manufacturers in packets of tens. The probability that a diskette produced by manufacturer A is defective is 0.05 whereas the probability that a diskette produced by manufacturer B is defective is 0.02. Find the probability that a randomly chosen packet contains exactly one defective diskette.

Since we have 0.6 from A and 0.4 from B, is it correct if I multiply 0.6 and 0.05 and sum it up with 0.4 times 0.02 to get the answer? There is something wrong.

Comment: Your calculation doesn't include the fact that there are 10 diskettes in each packet.

Comment: nor the restriction of 'exactly one'.

Answer (score 0):

First, you calculate the chance that exactly one diskette in a group of ten is faulty (and remaining 9 are not) - in two variants for two likelihoods of fault per manufacturer. Then you need to weigh the two probabilities by chance of picking a box from one or the other.

The first can be calculated as "chance that at least one is ten is faulty" times chance that "none of the remaining 9 are faulty".

Answer (score 0):

The probability  that a randomly selected package from manufacturer A contains exactly one defective diskette is given by the binomial distribution $Bern(n,k,p_A)$, where $n$ is the total number of diskettes in the package ($10$), $k$ is the number of the defective diskettes ($1$) and $p_A$ is the probability of a defective diskette from manufacturer A ($0.05$).

$p_1=\binom{10}{1}p_{A}^1(1-p_A)^9=10p_{A}^1(1-p_A)^9$

Equal for the probability of a randomly selected package from manufacturer B is:

$p_2=\binom{10}{1}p_{B}^1(1-p_B)^9=10p_{B}^1(1-p_B)^9$

So the asked probability is

$p=0.6p_1+0.4p_2$